# Integrating React-Redux with Microsoft Fluid framework

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-typescript, fluid-framework

I'm trying to integrate two different state management frameworks

1. React Redux
2. Microsoft Fluid Framework

Here is my observation

[image]

What is the best approach? react-redux is used for maintaining my local user state where as
Microsoft Fluid framework is used to broadcast my user activity to the connected nodes of my applications.

**For Example:**

A Helpdesk operator logins into applications and raises a ticket, when the complaint is raised it should be broadcasted to the connected mechanic sheds about the complaint. Here first-come-first server model is approached in solving that complaint, which mechanic ack the complaint then that particular complaint will be handed over for fixing.